# How to implement bulk insert in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I need to insert a array of emails  as different records into my contacts table. How can this be done.

```
Eg: @email = ["a@b.com", "c@d.com", "e@f.com", ... ]
```

I dont want to use.

```
  @email.each do |email|
     @contact = Contact.new
     @contact.email = email
     @contact.save
  end
```

This cause n insert quires. I just need a single insert query to insert these values. How can this be done in rails 3.0.9 (and ideally MySQL). Please help

Comment: See also: [Bulk Insert records into Active Record table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317837/bulk-insert-records-into-active-record-table) and [Batch insertion in rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784305/batch-insertion-in-rails-3).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**activerecord-import** implements AR#import

activerecord-import is a library for bulk inserting data using ActiveRecord.

see how it works:

```
books = []
10.times do |i| 
  books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}")
end
Book.import books
```

Project's home is on [Github](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) and it's [wiki](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/).

Comment: Speeds up a bulk insert significantly.

Comment: Also, related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718013/how-do-i-retrieve-a-list-of-created-ids-for-bulk-insert-in-active-record, see the second answer (not the accepted one). The raw SQL version does return all the ids.

Comment: And I've got a fork of the gem that not only does that, but automagically efficiently saves any subobjects and their children as well, so that you don't have to maintain parallel sets of arrays to save more complex objects. See here: https://github.com/GoodMeasuresLLC/activerecord-import

Comment: I successfully used this gem to reduce a 260k row data migration from 1 hour down to 6 minutes. Using Postgres.

Comment: This is fine. Thanks for the answer.. But, I would like to have this feature for a Model-less table in rails. Is that Possible..??  I am stuck at Model.import. I do not have Model here. Also, I can not create an empty model for this table. That is the situation. Please dont ask me why..

Comment: @Breenho In that case why not to prepare INSERT in batches by appending new strings and execute SQL request at result?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  @Anatoly, Yeah., That was the last option I had. Without using direct SQL queries, Is there a way to do so..?

Comment: @Breenho it depends on how do you create objects with Model-less table now

Comment: Hey @Anatoly., this is the link of my question . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612059/is-that-possible-to-make-use-of-activerecord-import-gem-for-a-model-less-table. Please, check this out for more details including the code snippet.

Comment: @Breenho I replied to you, please check it out

Comment: This is an old answer, but this is exactly what i want. But when I Implemented, getting this error "Column 'created_at' cannot be null". This library is not setting default value for created_at. Any idea why?

Comment: @Rajesh sure, check [this out](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/issues/426#issuecomment-307689597)

Comment: hmm, so I have to wait till they release an update, till then I'll use a plain bulk update query

Comment: @Rajesh v0.19.0

Answer (score 4):

You might also try [`upsert`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert), which is approximately as fast as `activerecord-import`, but only works (currently) with MySQL, Postgres, and SQLite3:

```
require 'upsert'
Upsert.batch(Contact.connection, Contact.table_name) do |upsert|
  emails.each do |email|
    upsert.row(email: email)
  end
end
```

Note that this involves one database query per record, but it's an "upsert," so you don't have to check if a record already exists. In your example, this isn't a concern, but in most applications it becomes one eventually.

Comment: Having one database query per record is exactly NOT bulk import. Bulk import is having one insert SQL statement with many parameter sets bound to it, so that you have only one database round trip, and hence it's fast.

Comment: `upsert` library started out using `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, which is bulk.

Comment: (oops, hit enter before i could fully explain myself) even though it doesn't do that anymore, it makes 1 trip to the db per record, i think that historical fact is why i unthinkingly didn't justify how `upsert` is, in my opinion, a form of bulk update. i would define bulk update as "setting new state across many records without regard to their current state" - how many db trips that takes is an (important) detail. "upserting" is a particular way of doing bulk. see https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert/commit/b8365d91fe68e450382119 for why i stopped using the 1-trip-per-batch method.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way without additional gem is to concat a string and execute it in one SQL insertion (http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/).

```
@email = ["a@b.com", "c@d.com", "e@f.com"]

time = Time.current.to_s(:db)

values = @email.map do |email|
  "('#{email}', '#{time}', '#{time}')"
end

sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (email, created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{values.join(', ')}"
Contact.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: I implemented this, but now I'm wondering if it's at risk of SQL injection if you are using something a bit more free form than an email.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a little monkey-patch for Active Record 3.2 to INSERT many new records with a single SQL query, check it out:

https://github.com/alexdowad/showcase/blob/master/activerecord/bulk_db_operations.rb