# Creating multiple records at once from comma seperated IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

so I have a textfield, where a user can put comma seperated card IDs, for example 1,2,3. When this user submits the form, I want to create a new record of each ID he submits. So one for 1, one for 2, one for 3.

How would I do that?

Thank you

Comment: You also may use bulk insert, please, see [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505263/how-to-implement-bulk-insert-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must parse input value from textfield in your controller. 
For example:

```
def update
   ids_input=params[:ids]
   ids_input.split(',').each { |id|
      Card.create(:some_id=>id,:other_column=>'some_value',:related_user=>current_user)
   }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ModelName.create(input_string.split(',').map{ |i| { :field => i.strip } })
```

`split` will split input on comma and map will generate an array of `{ :field => i }` where `:field` is your model's textfield.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish that, depending on your specific needs. 
One way would be to loop through all the entries in your controller, like @rogal111 is suggesting in his answer.

If you have a one-to-many relationship between your User and the Cards, which is most probably the way to go anyway, I would suggest that you accomplish it through a nested form. Ryan Bates has done some excellent [screencasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested%20form) on that one.