# How to eager loading in a method called from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eager-loading

I have a task like this:

```
namespace :company do
  task :update, [:code] => :environment do |t, args|
    company = Company.find_or_create_by(code: args[:code])
    company.update_from_local_data
  end
end
```

And this is the `Company` class.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  def update_from_local_data
    data = YAML.load(File.read(ENV['COMPANY_DATA_FILE']))
    update_items(data)
  end
  def update_items(item_array)
    item_array.each do |value|
      item = items.find_or_initialize_by(name: value[:name])
      item.update_attributes(value)
    end
  end
end
```

I confirmed that there is a lot of `SELECT` SQL query for this code.

In controller I can handle with it, but how can I use eager loading from rake task?

#### Edit

Thanks for Uri's comments I see how to improve performance for save several data to Database, but I still have problem how to call `find_or_initialize_by` for several items.

I found `:on_duplicate_key_update` option for `ActiveRecord.import`, but it can be used only with `MySQL` while I'm using `PostgreSQL`.

#### Edit 2

To explain what is the problem I created a [example project](https://github.com/ironsand/eager_loading_in_rake_task_question).

This is a result of `Company#update_from_local_data`.
I don't want `SELECT` query for every `Item`s.

How can I write it more efficiently?

```
c = Company.first
c.update_from_local_data
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."company_id" = ? AND "items"."name" = 'item0' LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."company_id" = ? AND "items"."name" = 'item1' LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."company_id" = ? AND "items"."name" = 'item2' LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."company_id" = ? AND "items"."name" = 'item3' LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."company_id" = ? AND "items"."name" = 'item4' LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."company_id" = ? AND "items"."name" = 'item5' LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."company_id" = ? AND "items"."name" = 'item6' LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."company_id" = ? AND "items"."name" = 'item7' LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."company_id" = ? AND "items"."name" = 'item8' LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."company_id" = ? AND "items"."name" = 'item9' LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
=> [{:name=>"item0"}, {:name=>"item1"}, {:name=>"item2"}, {:name=>"item3"}, {:name=>"item4"}, {:name=>"item5"}, {:name=>"item6"}, {:name=>"item7"}, {:name=>"item8"}, {:name=>"item9"}]
```

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317837/bulk-insert-records-into-active-record-table

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to speed up the find_or_initialize_by step.

```
def update_items( items ) 
  # 'items' is an array of attributes hashes

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

    names_array = items.map{ |attributes| attributes[:name] }
    existing_records = Company.where(name: names_array)

    records_by_name = existing_record.each_with_object({}) do |record, hash|
      name = record.name
      hash[name] = record
    end

    items.each do |attributes|
      name = attributes[:name]
      record = records_by_name[name] || Company.new

      # with validations and callbacks:
      #   record.update_attributes(attributes)

      # without validations:
      #   attributes.each{ |k, v| record[k] = v }
      #   record.save(validate: false)


      # without validations or callbacks:
      #   If you're using an older version of Rails,
      #   you can use record.save(:update_without_callbacks)
      #   For recent versions, you'll need to either write SQL-
      #   or disable all callbacks with skip_callbacks and then re-enable-
      #   them with set_callbacks
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, you find all the existing records in one go rather than executing individual search queries for each name.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all), which will return the number of entries updated. If 0 entries were updated, then you create the new record

   ```
   def update_items(item_array)
     item_array.each do |value|
       entries_updated = items.where(name: value[:name]).update_all(value)
       if entries_updated == 0
         items.create!(value)
       end
   end
   ```

   Notice that `create!` will raise an error if it can't create the record. You may wish to use just `create` and handle validation errors on your own.
2. Another way you can go about it, based on the interface you suggested on chat `items = load_all(item_array); items.update_all`, is

   ```
   def update_items(item_array)
     grouped = item_array.group_by {|i| i[:name] }
     items.where(name: grouped.keys).each do |item|
       data = grouped[item.name]
       item.assign_attributes(data)
       item.save! if item.changed? 
     end
   end
   ```

   That would give you less queries if not all items are changed frequently, but can be slow if `Company` has thousands of items, but you could break `item_array` into smaller groups and then perform that. Notice that there's no way to produce one update statement that will change multiple records based on different criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `name` column has unique value, unfortunately your code doesn't improve the performance in my case.

Comment: Yes, name has a unique value. So what's gonna happen is that `Company.where.update_all` will always only update the one `Company` with that given name, meeting the line where you do `item.update_attributes(value)`. Then if nothing is updated, where it returns 0, means there's no company with that name, so it proceeds to create such company with the data in `value`.

Comment: That way, the code will always run 1 or 2 queries that will not require loading information from the db, because `update_all` doesn't load data from the db, just runs a `update`, which in your case is based on an index. Where your code will always run a select, and then load the data or not, and then run an update.

Comment: I noticed now, your code updating `Company` class while I want to update or initialize `Item` class. I couldn't adjust your answer to my original code. Am I missing something?

Comment: ah true, you need to use `items`, updated the answer. All the conditions I mentioned still apply though.

Comment: oh, I get it. The problem is the `update` does access database to get `item` every time even if the local data file are not changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66730/discussion-between-rafb3-and-tetsu).