# rails bulk create objects from the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

How can I add dynamic fields to a rails form to create multiple objects from the same model? I'm able to do this with nested forms using the cocoon gem but for fields of the same model I can't figure it out. I tried to add fields dynamically trough js but without success! Can anyone point me on the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317837/bulk-insert-records-into-active-record-table