# How long should I allow activerecord-import to run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activerecord-import

**Rails Version:** 4.2.7

**Ruby Version:** 2.3.3

I am running a rake task to migrate several million objects from CSV and JSON file format into my postgres database.

I was attempting to utilize `activerecord-import` to speed up writing the objects to the database.

Simplifying the code down as much as possible, the first half dealt with object type one (which came from one data type) and the second half dealt with object type two.

The first object type iterated like so (simplified for the question):

```
importing_object_one_array = []
my_external_data.each do |element|
  new_element = ObjectOne.new(
                              title: element[0],
                              body: element[1]
                             )
  importing_object_one_array << new_element
end
ObjectOne.import importing_object_one_array, validate: false
```

This ran on roughly 250,000 objects, and wrote without a any issues, I've inspected in the console and the objects are successfully written.

However, object type two has a fair few extra objects, each roughly the same size and design as object type one.

There are roughly 4,040,000 of these.

How long should I wait for `ObjectTwo.import` to run? We're into hours now.

Alternatively, from a debugging perspective (as I would really rather not re-run this rake task unless I absolutely have to), what scripts or tactics would be useful to see if `ObjectTwo.import` really **is** currently running (even if it's taking forever) or if the task is hanging?

I inspected the rails console and we appear to still be at the same number of `ObjectTwo`'s in the database as before.

---

My only other thought is that as I didn't print out to the console before running `#import` (i.e. like `puts "Now starting import!"`) I don't have 100% proof that the objects building in the array has finished.

Comment: that's (one reason) why you would usually use something like `in_groups_of` and import a chunk at a time.

Comment: you can use `each_with_index` and each iteration, print the index to show progress. To speed it up, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317837/bulk-insert-records-into-active-record-table) for ways to bulk insert (you can split up your records into groups for bulk insertion)

Comment: Use a background processing tool, like [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), so you can parallelize your import

Comment: Split them in batches to be aware of progress

Comment: You also can use the Parallel gem https://github.com/grosser/parallel. It's very helpful to bulk insert big datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Since it would be very hard to guess in advance how much time it needs to solve your problem (it depends on database load, indexes, and many other factors), I strongly suggest you work in batches.

Moreover, this will allow your database to face one very big request, which can exhaust its RAM, CPU, and network resource.

So, you could do something similar as:

### If my_external_data is from an activerecord query

```rb
total_records_count = large_query.count 

large_query.find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |batch|
   puts("Progress: #{100*processed_records/total_records_count}%") 
   ObjectOne.import importing_object_one_array, validate: false
end
```

### If my_external_data is a list of classical ruby objects

```rb
total_records_count = guess_number_of_records_to_process

large_array.in_groups_of(1000) do |batch|
   puts("Progress: #{100*processed_records/total_records_count}%") 
   ObjectOne.import importing_object_one_array, validate: false
end
```

Use with preference solution 1 over solution 2, working directly with ActiveRecord and find_in_batches, which will iterate over your data with OFFSET and LIMIT SQL statements instead of putting all your records in RAM, then importing them.

If you could not re-design your query, expect the run time to be quite linear, excepted if your database resources are not well bigger than what is needed to process the batch; otherwise, run time will be quite unpredictable.